# is there any tool that allows redirecting output to env variable in windows *.cmd script?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I mean to use it like this:

```
echo some data | this-tool-m-searching-for -vn myvariable
```

or

```
time | this-tool-m-searching-for -vn current_time
```

etc..

and then

```
echo %myvariable%
```

would produce `some data` etc...

This is not about echo or time only, I mean any program that gives output to stdout.

Comment: Consider `echo %TIME%` and `echo %DATE%`. On http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ you can find plenty of code that touches the topic you are looking into.

Answer (score 3):

This is the usual construction, I believe:

```
for /F %i in ('time /t') do set current_time=%i
```

(as usual, the percent signs need to be doubled in a command script.)

Another construction, though awkward:

```
time /t > tempfile.txt
set /p current_time= < tempfile.txt
```

There appears to be no way to avoid the temporary file; if you use a pipe, the set command happens in a subprocess.  (In some situations you might be able to pipe the output to a second copy of your batch script, but that sort of thing can get ugly fast.)

*Additional*

To expand on my last point, in response to a question in the comments, here is an example batch file which pipes output into a new instance of itself:

```
if "%1" NEQ "" @goto %1
:step1
time /t | %0 step2
goto :eof
:step2
set /p current_time=
echo %current_time%
rem processing here...
```

I don't think this solution scales well for more complicated batch scripts.

Comment: Yes but it expands the `%i` (`%%i` in bath file) variable, and if program output contains some special characters you are in trouble. Pipe doesn't have this issue.

Comment: People do some amazing things with command scripts, but for my part if you need to deal with special characters I always recommend bailing out and using vbscript or powershell instead.

Comment: I know but I've written so much in *.cmd and it works well, the only weak link is here, this little tool and I'm saved.

Comment: I've added another possible approach.

Comment: how would you use the set command with a pipe? I see  echo abc | set /p  a=    <-- doesn't do it.

Comment: See here why using a pipe wouldn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446972/why-doesnt-set-p-work-after-a-pipe

Comment: @Indrek: note, however, that the top rated answer to that question gets the explanation wrong (although the proposed workarounds are fine).  The other answer gets it right; it doesn't work because the set command is happening in a separate instance of cmd.exe, i.e., in a subprocess as I already said.

Comment: @barlop: I've added an example batch file.  This is the only way I can think of to use the set command with a pipe, and it's not pretty.

Comment: @HarryJohnston The beginning is incorrect, yes, though it actually quotes the correct answer later. That quote does use different terminology ("new context" vs. "subprocess"), but the basic idea is the same.

Answer (score 2):

Try [export.exe](http://4sysops.com/archives/exportexe/), it seems to do exactly what you're after.

Comment: Cool, but a 'bit' bloated though - *216kB* for so tiny functionality.... And doesn't allow doing it thru pipe.

Comment: In the absence of source code, I'd recommend caution with this tool.  If it works as advertised, it must be doing DLL insertion or something equally nasty on the parent process, which means it might have unexpected side-effects.

Comment: (I'd also run it past a few online virus/malware scanners if I were you.)

Comment: And it just has, some ugly error came, something around writting to a parent process.

Comment: http://virusscan.jotti.org/pl/scanresult/a895c3fad30dcfba595d436b4fad019caccce5c2 - all ok, a stone dropped from my heart

Comment: why DLL insertion? it just has to read from STDIN and put the value into an Environment variable, works fine for me.

Comment: In Windows, each process has its own set of environment variables.  There is no supported way for an executable to set an environment variable for the parent process.  (As far as I know.)